# Docx4J - Clarification of needed dependencies

Tags: java, docx4j

I have the following code in a main application as sample to try docx -> pdf conversion:

```
    try {
        InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream("Hello World.docx");
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(templateInputStream);
        MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

        String outputfilepath = "test.pdf";
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputfilepath);
        Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage,os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The maven pom includes the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-JAXB-MOXy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-MOXy</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-export-fo -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
        <version>8.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

It outputs the following logs and stack trace:

```
[JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils - Couldn't get resource: docx4j.properties
[JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties - Couldn't find/read docx4j.properties; docx4j.properties not found via classloader.
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - java.version=17.0.1
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - MOXy JAXB implementation is in use!
[JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.docx4j.XmlUtils - Xalan jar missing from classpath; xslt not supported
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.XmlUtils - setProperty com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
[JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.docx4j.XmlUtils - actual SAXParserFactory: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.XmlUtils - setProperty com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
[JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.docx4j.XmlUtils - actual DocumentBuilderFactory: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager - Detected WordProcessingML package 
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager - Detected WordProcessingML package 
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3 - Instantiated package of type org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.utils.XPathFactoryUtil - xpath implementation: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl
[JavaFX Application Thread] INFO org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3 - package read;  elapsed time: 1097 ms
[JavaFX Application Thread] WARN org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.autodetect.FontInfoFinder - Skipping font file that failed to load previously: file:/System/Library/Fonts/AppleSDGothicNeo.ttc

[JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR org.docx4j.XmlUtils - Cannot find class 'org.docx4j.convert.out.common.XsltCommonFunctions'.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Cannot find class 'org.docx4j.convert.out.common.XsltCommonFunctions'.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.passErrorsToListener(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:876)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1083)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:1347)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.loadDefaultTemplates(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:98)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.getDefaultTemplate(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:85)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.getTemplates(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:76)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.process(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:64)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.process(AbstractWmlExporter.java:82)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.process(AbstractWmlExporter.java:32)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:80)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:711)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:744)
```

I can't see which dependencies are potentially missing. I tried also with the 11.4.8 variants as I am working on Java 17. I tried with Xalan and Xerces, but this gives other exceptions not being able to instantiate the SAXParser...

Anyone who can give some hints, please?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I need to check my build system. Extracting all to a core application without all the other dependencies it just worked out of the box.